# Spark dataframe random sampling based on frequency occurrence in dataframe

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, random, apache-spark-sql

**Input description**
I have a spark job with input dataframe with a column queryId. This queryId is not unique with respect to the dataframe. For example, there are roughly 3M rows in the spark dataframe with 450k distinct query ids.

**Problem**
I am trying to implement sampling logic and create a new column sampledQueryId which contains randomly sampled query id for each dataframe row by looking up query ids from the aggregate spark dataframe query id set.

**Sampling goal**

1. The restriction is that sampled query id shouldn't be equal to input query id.
2. Sampling should correspond to frequency of occurrence of query id in the incoming spark dataframe - ie given two query id q1 and q2, if the ratio of occurrence is 10:1(q1:q2), then q1 should appear approximately 10 times more in the sample id column.

**Solution tried so far**
I have tried to implement this through collecting the query ids into a list and lookup query id list with random sampling but have some suspicion based on empirical evidence that the logic doesn't work as expected for eg I see a specific query id getting sampled 200 times but a query id with similar frequency never gets sampled.

Any suggestions on whether this spark code is expected to work as intended?

```
val random = new scala.util.Random
val queryIds = data.select($"queryId").map(row => row.getAs[Long](0)).collect()
val sampleQueryId = udf((queryId: Long) =>  {
      val sampledId = queryIds(random.nextInt(queryIds.length))
      if (sampledId != queryId) sampledId else null        
})
val dataWithSampledIds = data.withColumn("sampledQueryId",sampleQueryId($"queryId"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Received response on different forum documenting for posterity's sake. The issue is that one random instance is being passed to all executors through the udf. So the n-th row on every executor is going to give the same output.

```
scala> val random = new scala.util.Random
scala> val getRandom = udf((data: Long) => random.nextInt(10000))
scala> spark.range(0, 12, 1, 4).withColumn("rnd", getRandom($"id")).orderBy($"id").show
+---+----+
| id| rnd|
+---+----+
|  0|6720|
|  1|7667|
|  2|3344|
|  3|6720|
|  4|7667|
|  5|3344|
|  6|6720|
|  7|7667|
|  8|3344|
|  9|6720|
| 10|7667|
| 11|3344|
+---+----+
```

This df had 4 partitions. The value of rrd for every n-th row is the same (e.g. id = 1, 4, 7, 10 are the same).The solution is to use rand() built-in function in Spark like below.

```
val queryIds = data.select($"queryId").map(row => row.getAs[Long](0)).collect()
val sampleQueryId = udf((companyId: Long, rand: Double) =>  {
      val sampledId = queryIds(scala.math.floor(rand*queryIds.length).toInt)
      if (sampledId != queryId) sampledId else null        
})
val dataWithSampledIds = data.withColumn("sampledQueryId",sampleQueryId($"queryId", rand()))
```